# Connecting to MySQL via SSL using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, ssl

I'm writing my first script that will connect via SSL to a MySQL database. I have been doing a lot of reading on the subject and have come across many options on how to set it up; some that apply to my situation and some that don't. Here is my situation:

The MySQL server is on the same machine as the script. My SSL Certificate is installed. Is it secure to simply connect to the database via a page that is using SSL with the following code?

```
Connecting via https://www.mysitehere.com/myscript.php

$con = mysql_connect("localhost", "username", "password", MYSQL_CLIENT_SSL);
if (!$con) {die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());}
mysql_select_db("my_database", $con);
```

Comment: I can see the need for a remote connection, but why would you need SSL for a *local* one? Would you not preferably connect through a socket? Not sure I understand.

Comment: oh, so are saying that I don't need the MYSQL_CLIENT_SSL

Comment: There's (generally) not much reason to use SSL if your server is on the same machine as your client -- it's not like your traffic is going over an insecure/untrusted link, and it will add computational overhead.

Comment: I can't see a reason why. If you have a man in the middle or other attack on your machine, it is compromised beyond salvation anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The MySQL server is on the same machine as the script. My SSL
>   Certificate is installed. Is it secure to simply connect to the
>   database via a page that is using SSL with the following code?

If you control the server(VPS) and PHP is on the same machine as MySQL(only need to allow connections from same machine) than it is pointless to use SSL for MySQL and will only result in overhead. You should just use firewall to protect MySQL [like you should also do with memcached](http://dustin.github.com/2010/08/08/memcached-security.html).

Otherwise you could read [this section from MySQL to configure SSL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/secure-using-ssl.html). I think involves a little bit more than just `$con = mysql_connect("localhost", "username", "password", MYSQL_CLIENT_SSL);`
. For example you need to configure your [SSL Certificate](http://wiki.welmers.net/en/Creating_SSL_Certificate):

```
mysqld --ssl-ca=ca-cert.pem \
       --ssl-cert=server-cert.pem \
       --ssl-key=server-key.pem
```

Comment: SSL encrypts the data in transit so its safer in the event it's intercepted, having a firewall setup only doesn't do this. You should have both in an ideal world.